# Accessing child of React Fragment

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, wrapper, ref

Say I have a component  that should wrap a child component and use an IntersectionObserver to monitor when the child appears on screen, and then fade it in.

I could implement something like this:

```
function FadeIn(props: PropsWithChildren) {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  //Fade in logic
  return <div ref={ref}>{props.children}</div>;
}
```

but this introduces an additional  element, which may break something.
I would prefer to be able to do this:

```
function FadeIn(props: PropsWithChildren) {
  //Fade in logic
  return <>{props.children}</>;
}
```

Here I use a fragment instead of a div, but fragments cant take a ref, so there's nothing I cant actually act on.

Essentially I'm looking for a non-intrusive way to implement a React wrapper Component that provides some functionality to its children, without disturbing the DOM or editing the child itself. Can this be done?

Comment: What about something like [React Transition Group](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/tree/v1-stable), you can both provide fade in functionality and pass a ref, I can write an example answer if you think that will help

Comment: @Harrison could you perhaps expand on how React Transition Group is using React.cloneElement internally to solve my issue(is this the trick?)? The fade in example provided is just an example, I'm more interested in how this type of functionality can be implemented than in the fading itself.

Comment: I would be wary of using `cloneElement`, even React themselves say ["Using cloneElement is uncommon and can lead to fragile code."](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement#:~:text=Using%20cloneElement%20is%20uncommon%20and%20can%20lead%20to%20fragile%20code.) If you want to use something like `cloneElement` you should edit your question to include that in your example code. Or provide a CodePen of your code so the community can replicate the issue better and provide more relevant solutions

Comment: @Harrison I only mention cloneElement because that seems to be whats used inside the React Transition Group mentioned by you. If this is not common or good practice I'm interested in what would be. Also maybe I'm misunderstanding the source of React Transition Group.

Comment: Oh it, may implement in under the surface, but I imagine they've likely developed heavily with it and I've never used `cloneElement` directly

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of `Transition` using [React Transition Group](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/tree/v1-stable)

This implementation would look something like this:
(you can still insert a `ref` if needed, `Transition` takes a `ref` prop.
Note that the setup is different if you're [forwarding a ref](https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef#forwardref)

```js
import { Transition } from "react-transition-group";

interface RightMenuProps {
  // some props
  visible: boolean; // if the item is visible
}

const RightMenu: React.FC
  <React.PropsWithChildren<RightMenuProps>
> = ({
  // some props
  visible,
  children,
}) => {
  return (
    <Transition in={visible} timeout={0} mountOnEnter>
      {transitionState => (
        <div
          className={
            `RightMenu ${transitionState}`
          }
        >
          {chiildren}
        </div>
      )}
    </Transition>
  )
}
```

Using the `transitionState` would then allow you to style it in your own preferred way

```css
.RightMenu {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  width: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out, min-width 0.2s ease-in-out;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.RightMenu.entered {
  min-width: 400px;
  visibility: visible;
  border-left: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.RightMenu.exiting {
  visibility: visible;
}

.RightMenu.exited {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
}
```

The available states are defined as:

```js
type TransitionStatus = "entering" | "entered" | "exiting" | "exited" | "unmounted"
```

This example uses `"react-transition-group": "^4.3.0"`, and the types from `"@types/react-transition-group": "^4.2.3"`; there are likely newer versions of this package but some of this may still apply.

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the FadeIn component in this way

```
import React { forwardRef, PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

 function FadeIn(props: PropsWithChildren, ref: React.Ref<any>) {
  // Fade in logic
  return <div ref={ref}>{props.children}</div>;
 }
```

and then you can use ref to access or interact with the wrapped content

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const myRef = useRef(null);

  return (
   <FadeIn ref={myRef}>
    {/* Your content goes here */}
   </FadeIn>
  );
};
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your solution is exactly the case I specified I wanted to avoid in my question. You are introducing an additional <div> to wrap the actual content to be manipulated. The only difference is that you raised the ref up one more level.